# how to give html file values from xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, combobox

I have iphone app i have create a combo box i want that combo box should get value from xcode direct not from the html file so how to do that i am using following code to get combobox in html file

```objc
NSString *htmlPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"combo.html"];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
```

combo.html:

```
 <html>   
 <SELECT NAME="food" SIZE="10" style="width: 200px;" style="height: 100px "> 
 <OPTION VALUE="0">OK</OPTION>
 <OPTION VALUE="1">Good</OPTION>
 <OPTION VALUE="2">Best</OPTION>
 <OPTION VALUE="3">Average</OPTION>
 </SELECT> 
 </html>
```

Comment: is it an IPHone app or web app? if it is web app  i think you can't use xcode in web app

Comment: it is in iphone app i am using webview to load this combobox

Comment: @ZafarYousafi it is not web app it is native app i am using this html file in web view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I think that you're asking whether you can load an HTML file from your app bundle, then dynamically insert some different HTML content, from your app ... right?

If so, you can certainly do that.

First, we'll load the content into a **mutable** string:

```objc
NSString *htmlPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"combo.html"];
NSError *error;
NSMutableString *htmlContent = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile: htmlPath 
                                                                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                                   error: &error];
```

To **insert** a new option/value in the combo box, use something like this:

```objc
// look for the start of the combo box called "food"
NSRange range = [htmlContent rangeOfString: @"select name=\"food\"" 
                                   options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // search for the end tag </select>
    range.length = htmlContent.length - range.location;
    NSRange end = [htmlContent rangeOfString: @"</select>" 
                                     options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                       range: range];
    if (end.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *newChoice = @"Awesome!";  // get this dynamically however you want
        NSString *newOption = 
           [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<option value=\"4\">%@</option>\n", newChoice];
        [htmlContent insertString: newOption atIndex: end.location];
        NSLog(@"htmlContent = %@", htmlContent);
    }
}
```

If you want to **change** the displayed *value* on one existing combo box option, then use code like this:

```objc
NSString *optionTwoHtml = @"<option value=\"2\">";
NSRange optionTwo = [htmlContent rangeOfString: optionTwoHtml 
                                       options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (optionTwo.location != NSNotFound) {
    int start = optionTwo.location + optionTwoHtml.length;
    // search for the end tag </option>
    optionTwo.length = htmlContent.length - optionTwo.location;
    NSRange end = [htmlContent rangeOfString: @"</option>" 
                                     options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                       range: optionTwo];
    if (end.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *newValue = @"Better Than Best!";
        NSRange oldRange = NSMakeRange(start, end.location - start);
        [htmlContent replaceCharactersInRange: oldRange 
                                   withString: newValue];
        NSLog(@"htmlContent = %@", htmlContent);
    }
}
```

**Note** this code just shows you what you can do.  It's not optimized for performance.  The HTML content you showed is very small, so it really wouldn't matter how efficient the parsing code is.  If you use a much larger HTML file, you may want to optimize a little.

Comment: and how to get the selected value from combox box like ok selected how to get that from this combox box and used in other class in xcode

Comment: @user1520252, well you didn't say you needed that, in your question. If you had, I would have asked why you're doing it this way. iOS apps are not web apps.  iOS has built-in controls that you should use if you want things like combo boxes (`UIPickerView`).  If you accept this answer, and then add this request into your question above, or in a new question, I'll take a look at it. In the future, please try to describe your whole problem when asking for solutions.  Thanks.